# Android 2.3 and google maps API v2

Tags: java, android

Today I tried to use google maps api v2 for Android 2.3.3
My steps:

- got SHA1 code from debug.keystore
- create a new project in google apis console
- register a new id
- enabled google maps android api v2
- create an android key using as input SHA1;it.mappe   (it.mappe is my
  package)
- get API key
- update AndroidManifest file:

  ```
  <permission android:name="it.mappe.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="it.mappe.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"` />

  <application     android:allowBackup="true"    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="MY_KEY" />

          <activity
              android:name="it.mappe.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>
  ```
- my main activity

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
  ```
- my activity_main:

  ```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
  ```
- copy directory  `ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` to root of your project
- add `/extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar` as
  external jar
- add next line to the `YOUR_PROJECT/project.properties`
  `android.library.reference.1=google-play-services_lib`

When i run it on my samsung galaxy S (with google play services apk), it crashs and logcat shows this errors

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.mappe/it.mappe.MainActivity}: 

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    at it.mappe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/it.mappe-2.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    ... 19 more
```

some suggestions?

EDIT

here my main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Please post the actual content of `main.xml`

Comment: you can see it, under EDIT :)

Comment: were u able to run google map v2 in android emulator?

Comment: i don't use emulator, i use my old galaxy s. you need to have google play services installed on your device, without it you can't use the new gmaps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<fragment>` should be in all lowercase.

Also, you are using `Activity` (not `FragmentActivity`) with `SupportMapFragment`, and I doubt that combination will work.

Comment: sorry code function of stackoverflow didn't work goog with xml tags, it's lower case inside the code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: @CommonsWare, My application also need google maps version2 in API level 10. I am using FragementActivity and class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in main.xml. but i get error mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); when run in device. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the target Google SDK version in the project.properties and the support lib(Android.jar) versions are the same.