# Android Google Maps V2 and old SDK targeting

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying to integrate Google Maps into Android App.I am Android noob and sort of confused on how to do this the right way.My first issue was that Using API 4.0 based emulator I accomplished the setup outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) successfully, but when running it showed no map - only map controls.Then I found that it's impossible to debug Google Maps V2 on emulator.So I tried to run it on device.The device is HTC with Android 2.3.5 .The app had been constantly crashing once I uploaded it for test to the phone.Then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733581/android-2-3-and-google-maps-api-v2)  I found the guy  using :

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

in the  node ,rather than this:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" //from Google maps setup webpage
```

Can anyone explain why?I Also found that I had to replace my activity super class from Activity to FragmentActivity which is also not covered in Google's docs.

Another thing:when selecting the device to debug on I see a warning icon for my HTC phone (see below)
[image]

What does the warning mean?

And here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.helloworld"
       android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true"/>
  <permission
     android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
   <uses-permission  android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Do all those Google official docs target only the latest APIs?

Here is the error stack trace ( if using setup as in Google Maps [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) )

> 12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-02 19:27:55.345:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11590): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  ... 11 more 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.helloworld-2.apk]
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471) 12-02
>   19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
>   12-02 19:27:55.345: E/AndroidRuntime(11590):  ... 19 more

Comment: what does the stack trace say when it crashes? you get that warning because in your manifest you dont have that version of android as being supported ie your min SDK is something like 14 (android 4.0)

Comment: No , I do have.Minimum version set to 10 which is 2.3.5 .When it crashes ,the debugger shows "Source not found"

Comment: Now it works ok.It crashes if I do it "the original" way....